# Passing an object in RedirectToAction

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a controller that has received a POST back, and has processed what the user has requested. I then build an object, and now, want to RedirectToAction..

```
return RedirectToAction() ("Index", "Location", r);
```

Where r is the well named object I am working with. But on the target action, r is null.

```
public ActionResult Index(LocationByAddressReply location)
```

Now, I read a few posts on here about this, but am battling to understand.

An option put forward wasL

```
TempData["myObject"] = myObject;
```

But that seems ... strange. Not type safe. Is this the most suitable way to pass objects?

Comment: RedirectToAction does exactly that it redirects you.  Your alternative  might be to use a Session instead.

Comment: you can pass an object in your `RedirectToAction("Index", "Location", new { object myObject } )`

Comment: A few questions about this already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352015/redirecttoaction-with-complex-deep-object-fails
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9375279/how-to-pass-class-via-redirecttoaction

Comment: Dave A - I tried that, but am still getting null. How would I access this object on the receiving side?

Comment: @DaveA Those are `RouteValues`, completely different. Craig: Your only option is to use something that relies on `Session` or persist it to a database.. so `Session` or `TempData` are your only options.

Comment: Thanks Simon... I'll go with TempData... but I need to clear it after I grad the data, right? Or it could get pretty full?

Comment: ooops, thats true. only primitives can be passed. my bad.

Comment: @DaveA `TempData` is only persisted until you access an item with the same key. So `TempData["blah"] = 12; int i = (int)TempData["blah"];` will remove the data afterwards.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead, I never suggested TempData

Comment: @DaveA Whoops I meant to tag the OP haha. My bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can get values using `TempData` on redirect. 
Your method should looks like:

```
public ActionResult YourRedirectMethod()

{
   TempData["myObject"]=r;
   return RedirectToAction() ("Index", "Location");

}
```

and

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   LocationByAddressReply location=null;
   if(TempData["myObject"]!=null)
    {
          location=(LocationByAddressReply)TempData["myObject"];
    }
}
```

In this way you get values of your model that was previousely set on redirect method.

Comment: Thanks. I am implementing this. How do you try ensure the 'TempData' store doesn't get too big? Remove the item after grabbing it?

Comment: TempData will automatically get empty. Means Temp data use during the current and subsequent request only. This is difference between session and tempdata

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/313572/what-is-tempdata-collection-used-for-in-asp-net-mvc for more information.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this in two ways:

**First option**, if you have a simple model

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Location", new { Id = 5, LocationName = "some place nice" });
```

That one needs maintenance, think about if you need to later on add properties to your model. So you can be fancy and do it like this:

**Second option**, `UrlHelper` is your friend

```
return Redirect(Url.Action("Index", "Location", model));
```

The second option really is the right way of doing it. `model` is the object that you built and want to pass to your `LocationController`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think using `TempData` is the right solution, refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/386681/asp-net-mvc-tempdata-good-or-bad-practice#answer-393112). You  could instead, pass an anonymous object made of your `r` object. For example, if you have this:

```
public class UserViewModel 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }
}

public ActionResult Index(UserViewModel uvm) 
{ 
    ...
}
```

you could pass that `UserViewModel` like this:

```
public ActionResult YourOtherAction(...)
{
    ...
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Location", new 
                                                 { 
                                                     id = /*first field*/,
                                                     returnUrl = /*second field*/ 
                                                 });
}
```

ASP.NET MVC parses this into the object you are expecting as an argument in `Index` action. Give it a try if you haven't already switched your code for using `TempData`.